# I want to prove or disprove "∀ open interval I, m∗(I) = m∗(I∩E)+m∗(I∩E^c)" implies "E is lebesgue measurable".

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

> Let $E \subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Then
>
> For all open interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ , $m^∗(I) = m^∗(I∩E)+m^∗(I∩E^c) \Rightarrow E \textrm{ is lebesgue measurable}$

I want to solve this statement. However, I can’t.

I need your advice.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Are you sure the statement is true? By [Carathéodory's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion), $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if the equation holds for any *arbitrary* set $I \subseteq \mathbb R$, not just intervals.

Comment: Can you take a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3538939/282784

I found proof of my question. Some of you may need proof, so I leave the link here.